# ESP8266 TCP stop working on "heavy" traffic

Tags: tcp, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

## Context

Hello everybody. I'm working on a project where I need to send about 60 TCP sockets per second to my ESP8266 in order to change a light bulb intensity "in real time". The sockets are really small, like 5 bytes.

## Hardware

Server device: *NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)*

Client device: *Linux 16.04 PC* sending data with Node.js

-The NodeMCU board is running the last Arduino firmware: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

## The problem

When I send a lot of TCP packets every second, the ESP8266 wifi eventually stops working. The cpu keeps working but it won't reply any ping or TCP request.

I created a really small program just to test this bug, and here it is the [wireshark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnrKK.png).

(**192.168.1.11**) -> ESP8266

(**192.168.1.101**) -> Linux PC

As you can see, there is a moment where the ESP8266 stops sending ACKs. Sometimes it will recover after a few seconds, sometimes it doesn't.

Here is the code I use in the ESP8266:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define TCP_PORT 17717
#define PIN_LED 2
#define MAX_INTENSITY 255
#define MAX_PWM_FREQ 1023

WiFiServer server(TCP_PORT);
WiFiClient socket;

const char * ssid = "MyWifi";
const char * password = "MyPass";



void setLed(byte intensity) {
    analogWrite(PIN_LED, (int)(intensity/(float)MAX_INTENSITY * MAX_PWM_FREQ));
}



void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    pinMode(PIN_LED, OUTPUT);
    setLed(0);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.print("Ready! IP = ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    server.begin();
}



void loop() {
    if (server.hasClient()) {
        socket = server.available();
        while (socket.connected()) {
            if (socket.available()) {
                setLed(socket.read());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Probably lwip (leightweight IP stack) keeps allocating packets. Even closed connections remain in a `WAITING` state before being deallocated. So you'll eventually run out of memory (~40kB heap on the esp8266) or TCP packet buffers.

Comment: So do you know if I can force that deallocation? I tried `socket.flush()` after reading a byte but it doesn't seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: you just can't do that. send more stuff fewer times per second and interpret the more-complex incoming instructions in software. just sending 2 bytes instead of one halves the overhead...

Comment: TCP has a lot of overhead. Can you use UDP? For your application a couple of lost packets/commands is fine.

Comment: I can't send bigger sockets because I need it to be a real-time communication. I'll see if UDP works fine!

Comment: I am not as much familiar with the firmware from Arduino IDE, but I suspect it to be a little bit modified espressif fw. Here is what it says in SDK "All tasks and timers should complete in less 
than 2 ms and must complete in less than 500 ms or the watchdog timer will reset 
the MCU. "

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the **MAX_SOCK_NUM** is **4** defined in the **Ethernet.h** file. So we cannot connect more than 4 TCP connections which is restricted by the small memory size of the TCP/IP stack in ESP8266 and if we exceed the fixed number the board crashes.